# I can no longer get the links to work in my webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mailto

Firstly I apologise as I have only limited experience of HTML, CSS and Bootstrap so this may be something really simple that I have overlooked.

I created a website for a friend that has mailto links on a button. They were working but now they don't. Can't figure what I have done that stops it from working.

The code is:

```html
<ol class="align-content-center btn btn-lg btn-secondary button2 mt-3" href="mailto:hello@wandering.yoga?subject=Website%20booking%20Online-Zoom">Book Here</ol>
```

The mailto link works by itself in isolation but clicking on the "Book now " button does nothing.

The page is here [Yoga Website](https://wandering.yoga/courses.html)

Comment: I believe it has to be a link aka  `<a>`. I don't think href="" works with ol

Comment: Your ol element is not legal HTML. There are only a few things it can contain directly - usually the text would be in an li. However, you probably don't want an ol at all but an anchor (a) element. And in that case the text would be OK where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` work only on `<a>` tag.

So try that :

```html
<a href="mailto:hello@wandering.yoga?subject=Website%20booking%20Online-Zoom">
    <ol class="align-content-center btn btn-lg btn-secondary button2 mt-3">Book Here</ol>
</a>
```

Comment: As [A Haworth says in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966044/i-can-no-longer-get-the-links-to-work-in-my-webpage#comment128875120_72966044), an `ol` with only text as a child is not legal HTML.

Comment: @Mal it will work, at least in some browsers, but it will fail HTML validation so don't use it exactly as it is.